# How to split an array in a for loop Python

Tags: python, arrays, svm, prediction

I have the following array:

`prediction = [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0]`

I am looping over images in a test dataset, and what I want is for each image, to get the corresponding prediction. So for example, for image1 the prediction would be 0, for image2 it would be 1 etc.

I've been trying something like this, I know it's wrong but it gives you an idea of what I want:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=100)

for file in glob.glob(test_path + "/*.jpg"):
.
.
.
    prediction = clf.predict(X_test)

    for i in prediction:
        prediction = prediction[i]
        print(prediction)
```

(I've omitted the part of the code that isn't relevant, but if you need to see it i'll edit the post and add it in)

Is there a way to do what I'm asking?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
for index,file in enumerate(glob.glob(test_path + "/*.jpg")):
    prediction[index] #your prediction for the indexth image
```

This works for any iterable:

```
for i, each in enumerate(iterable):
    print('The'+str(i)+'th element in your iterable is'+str(each))
```